# Group horizontal form elements vertical

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a horizontal form which should contains a form-group having input elements vertical aligned:

[image]

I want to achieve the alignment like

[image]

I have tried to mix with form-group and similar without any success.

Here is my code http://www.bootply.com/cmTOqxCTH8

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/obCzGHERip here you go.

Comment: Thanks, is there the possibility to align all select elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up nested columns. Please check the reult.

[image: Please check the reult]

http://www.bootply.com/5pqe45yxx1

---

UPD. We can align all three elements, if needed.

[image]

http://www.bootply.com/zRCs4lZLXS

Comment: Thanks, is there the possibility to align all select elements?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a white cube the same size as the one you have, and put it before the second key. It should work.